# Windows 8 pagefile on usb FLASH

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive, swap, pagefile

Not duplicate :)

Windows 8 hides usb **flash** drives in the list of virtual memory drive list. The picture taken when I installed 2 usb flash drives but they are not in the list.
Any body knows the trick to add them here?

[image]

Comment: Salam, Can you find the reason?

Comment: I found a good response here: http://superuser.com/questions/589031/windows-readyboost-purpose , in **Jamie Hanrahan** answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that. Microsoft introduced **ReadyBoost** with Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 as a potential way to improve the performance of Windows Virtual Memory.

Ready Boost only improves performance when your USB drive has faster access times then your hard drive does. For most systems, setting a fixed minimum size and no maximum size for virtual memory will provide the best performance.

To make flash drive for **ReadyBoost** Just take the properties of flash drive and do following,

[image]

Comment: Thanks i know that but the question is about pagefile , not readyboost .

Comment: Traditional paging to flash memory is a terrible idea.  See my response to one of your comments elsewhere.

Comment: @Shinrai I know technically very bad exception occurs when the pagefile suddenly hides but any modern OS should easily handle that exception . Let's think you have hotplug sata/sas/etc disks and OS uses them for pagefile . what happens when you unplug that drive(s) ?

Comment: @OmidKosari - Bad things happen, but anybody using hotswap disks should be aware of that...it's a lot less common than flash memory.  The point I'm trying to make is that *Microsoft doesn't want you to do this*.  You could probably find some workaround by getting your flash drive to identify itself as non-removable media by editing the firmware on it, but offhand I can't think of any other approach I would take.  And I can't think of any usage situation where it would be the right decision, that's the main thing.  I don't know why you're thinking this is something you should do, but it's not.

Comment: ReadyBoost uses SuperFetch to predict blocks that might be read and write them to flash memory to be read if the hard drive is busy.  This *may* speed a low memory system, but it has nothing to do with virtual memory.

Answer (score 2):

An paragraph of here: [Windows Readyboost purpose](https://superuser.com/questions/589031/windows-readyboost-purpose) , in **Jamie Hanrahan** answer:

Nor will Windows allow you to create a pagefile on a USB drive. Reason: If Windows needed to read pagefile contents from a USB drive, and someone had pulled the USB drive from its port, there would be no other place to get that data. If it was kernel mode v.a.s. being paged in Windows would have to crash, just as it does on any other attempt to read a kernel page from a failing drive (various bugcheck codes mentioning "kernel inpage error").