# Readyboost is a replacement for Pagefile

Tags: windows-7, windows, pagefile, readyboost

1. Readyboost is a replacement for Pagefile?
2. After activating Readyboost can we disable page file?
3. Does the OS still use a Pagefile after activating Readyboost?

Comment: in `http://superuser.com/questions/589031/windows-readyboost-purpose` **Jamie Hanrahan** well explained.

Comment: Short answers: 1) No. 2) No. 3) Yes.